# On IIS vm use localhost or public domain name

Tags: .net, web-services, iis

I have multiple applications running on a iis vm. These applications are publicly available through site.example.com and site2.example.com.

They also connect with each other through a webservice in .net.

Which is better to use Localhost to connect or using the public domain names? Especially looking in performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the localhost, the request goes through DNS and using the public domain, the browser will looking for IP address from DNS first this is the main difference.

But talking about the performance improvement localhost will have batter performance compare to the public domain, but for maintenance purposes, it's better to use the public domain.

Comment: Hello Jalpa, Thank you for your response. So if I understand correctly if I want better network performance go with Localhost. I think maintenance is not big on my case since the current url's are all set in configuration file and will not change.

Comment: @BartvanDuinkerken correct if you need better network performance use localhost. but does not make much difference. you could test it by yourself.